# Component Diagram eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, uml, components, xmi, component-diagram

I've been looking for 3 days for a an eclipse plugin that helps you to create a visual component diagram. I also want to be able to extract the XMI file that corresponds to the diagram I create. So far I tried [EMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/), and [GMF](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/), but after installing them, I couldn't find what I need. I only got stuff like this:

[image]

I have no problem with using a non-eclipse based tool, as long as it serves my need.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Try Papyrus as @Tanya said in her answer.it is a very handy solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is [Altova UModel 2014](http://www.altova.com/download/umodel.html). I downloaded a trial version, and it perfectly matches my need. I can buy it later. No problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Papyrus](http://www.eclipse.org/papyrus/). EMF and GMF are frameworks to create your own diagram editors, Papyrus is an open-source tool which is based on them. Component diagram is one of supported UML diagrams. Steps to create a new diagram are described [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Papyrus_User_Guide#Tutorials_on_UML_modeling_with_Papyrus).